# How to get user_id with this code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code here:

```
$selectUserQuery = 'SELECT user_id, email_address, password FROM user WHERE email_address = :email_address AND password = :password AND confirm_status = 1';
$prepSelectUser = $conn->prepare($selectUserQuery);
$prepSelectUser->bindParam(':email_address', $emailEnc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prepSelectUser->bindParam(':password', $passwordEnc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prepSelectUser->execute();
$userResult = $prepSelectUser->fetchAll();
$userCount = count($userResult);
```

I select the email address and password to see if they match (this is for login) and I need the user_id to start a session with the user_id as its value. However, the fetchAll() function returns an array of the results, but I need the user_id separately, only to use it as a value for the session.

How do I fetch the user_id separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ( $userResult AS $row ) {
    var_dump($row[0]);
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is how I've used your code with the session: $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['user_id'];. However, it's printing "string(2) "56"" at the top of the page. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: @user3456043 - you have an array of mysql result rows in $userResult. While cycling through it you'll find `user_id` in the first element on each cycle. var_dump() is there only for illustration where to look for it. You can safely adjust the code according to your needs.

Comment: All right thx bro. I removed the var_dump function and it's working fine. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It should be in Userresult::

normaly is hould be:

```
$userResult[0]['user_id'] (1st user)
$userResult[1]['user_id'] 2th user
$userResult[5]['user_id'] 6th user....
```